# Why won't arcpy create my table?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am getting an error

> Failed to execute: Input Table: Parameters are not valid. ERROR
>   000732: Input Table: Dataset mytable does not exist or is not
>   supported Failed to execute (AddField).

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback
arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\school\\GEO614\\PythonPrimer\\Chapter06\\Data\\cursors.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outpath = "L:\\school\\GEO614\\PythonPrimer\\Chapter06\\MyData\\exercise6.gdb"
outname = 'mytable'
arcpy.CreateTable_management(outpath, outname)
arcpy.AddField_management(outname, 'LakeFC_ID', 'SHORT')
arcpy.AddField_management(outname, 'Lake_Name', 'TEXT', '50')
arcpy.AddField_management(outname, 'Lake_Info_ID', 'LONG')
arcpy.AddField_management(outname, 'Lake_Temp', 'SHORT')
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set your workspace to a different GDB than the one you include in your outpath. So it creates the table in the GDB specified by your outpath, but because you then only supply the table name to the add field tool, the Add Field tool looks in the GDB you set as your workspace, and cannot find the table. 
Make the workspace and outpath the same, or just supply the arcpy.env.workspace as the first parameter to the CreateTable tool, or join the outpath and outname variables using os.path.join and supply that to the Add Field tool, and it will work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

As there are multiple other reasons 000732 seems to pop up for arcpy users, if you are trying to utilize user input file paths and concatenate string variables with them, this solution helped me after hours of searching here and elsewhere online:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/getting-full-path-of-layer-selected-in-drop-down-box-for-arcgis-python-script-to

Comment: Please don't just include a link, but quote the relevant parts from that page in your answer.